# for each file in mail message can you fix?

Tags: powershell

I am looking how to attach a random file from a folder .
I tried this

```
$files =(Get-ChildItem “C:\Users\adm\script\signature\”)
Foreach($file in $files) { 
    $signature =Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\adm\script\signature\$file" 
} 

Send-MailMessage -From "administrator@corp.internal" -to "administrator@corp.internal" -Subject "mot de passe compte windows" -Attachments $signature  -body "$bodysignature" -BodyAshtm -SmtpServer "smtp.test"
```

but only 1 files are attached to the mail message .
Do you know how to fix that and why the for each are executed one time only ?

Thank you

Comment: Please do not edit tags into the subject of your question. Accepting an answer is sufficient for marking the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `$signature` get's replaced on every iteration in the foreach, not appended to (`+=`).
For a better overview I suggest to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.0).

```
$Attachments = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\adm\script\signature\").FullName
$param = @{
    From        = "administrator@corp.internal"
    To          = "administrator@corp.internal"
    Subject     = "mot de passe compte windows" 
    Attachments = $Attachments  
    Body        = "$bodysignature" 
    BodyAshtm   = $True
    SmtpServer  = "smtp.test"
}
Send-MailMessage @param
```

Comment: i will read your link to but if 

Can you explain little your code because I don't know this way and I know all variable from my code so it will be better for me to understand

I believe that the mail will be by this @param but for me that so strange because usually we use $ .Maybe you use @ because powershell will keep like that ?

how you code work because for me with my knowdelege if i saw this code I believe after FullName the script will attach one file and then continious .This thing "." mean come back like | ?
Thank you so much that perflectly fine .

Comment: There is a link attached to [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.0) explaining that all the parameters are stuffed into a hashtable and passed to the cmdlet. The `Attachments` parameter expects file path(es). Enclosing the gci in parentheses and suffixing it with `.FullName` is equivalent to `Get-ChildItem X:\path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`  but much shorter

Comment: your code are perflectly fine but when i try to add the file from another path 
I have an error because I don't know how to fix that .

Comment: After lot try ,I found how to do that .
$Attachments += (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\adm\script\picture\").FullName

The + work fine ,hope it was the good code ?

Comment: Of course, if it works for you. `+=` appends to a string/collection resp. adds to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your search is not recursive.

Try:

```
  Get-ChildItem “C:\Users\adm\script\signature\” -Recurse
```

Depending on which PowerShell version you are using (dump it via `$PSVersionTable`) `Get-ChildItem` has an additional `-File` parameter, for only returning files, not folders.

So on PowerShell version 5, you can use

```
 Get-ChildItem “C:\Users\adm\script\signature\” -Recurse -File
```

on older versions, you've to use

```
Get-ChildItem “C:\Users\adm\script\signature\” -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help .
if I understood 
-recurse = mean folder inside of this folder .

Hope you have another Ideas also I tried $signature += but does not work for this .
My PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117